# How to assign marker.title by coordinate (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have `longitude` and `latitude` because I use `didLongPressAtCoordinate` and for now I want to assign `marker.title` to title of this `coordinate`.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    self.googleMapsView.clear()
    self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = false
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView
    marker.title = --> //my problem


}
```

i can't find good solution for that

Comment: Hey scbas1000, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very vague, and has little chance of being answered. Please visit out guide on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks for your attention , i edit it , now is it right i think

Comment: @scbas1000 no, your question is still very vague and you have not posted any code showing what you have so far. Post the code you have, clearly discussing what you have working at the minute, what you are trying to achieve (examples will help) and then list what the error  / issue it is that you are facing in getting there

Comment: @scbas1000 what is `//my problem` supposed to mean?

Comment: i can't find good solution just that

Comment: you want to give title to this marker -> its address?

Comment: yes , with its longitude and latitude , thanks

Comment: Is your input desired locations `address` somewhere, anywhere in your code or just these coordinates?

Comment: no , i touch somewhere in map and after i have longitude and latitude and i need its title (or address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your address like this :-

```
  func getAddressForLatLng(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees, completionBlock : ((addrs : String)->Void)) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "\(baseUrl)latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)&key=\(serverKey)")
    print(url)


    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    if let result = json["results"] as? NSArray {
        if let address = result[0]["address_components"] as? NSArray {
            let number = address[0]["short_name"] as! String
            let street = address[1]["short_name"] as! String
            let city = address[2]["short_name"] as! String
            let state = address[4]["short_name"] as! String
            let zip = address[6]["short_name"] as! String
            print("\(number) \(street), \(city), \(state) \(zip)")
            completionBlock(addrs: "\(number) \(street), \(city), \(state) \(zip)")

        }
    }
}
```

Update your **didLongPressAtCoordinate** function :-

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    self.googleMapsView.clear()
    self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = false
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView
    getAddressForLatLng(coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude) { (addrs) in

        marker.title = addrs
        marker.snippet = "\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)"

    }


}
```

Mind that :- **baseUrl** And **serverKey** are your Google console baseUrl and serverKey

Comment: You do realize that state and city do not go to constant spots and that your code is wrong quite often. On top of that it is strictly written to work with a majority of the USA and wouldn't work the majority outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to geocode the coordinates. You have a limitation of 50 times you can do this per minute (set by google), so be efficient with use of doing so. [Here is a tutorial on the process](http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/)

Once you have the address, you just say

`marker.title = "\(theAddressVariableName)\n\nLat: \(coordinate.latitude)\nLon: coordinate.longitude"`

Format it however you want. Also, I don't understand why you would have the line of code `self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = false` inside of that function. It should probably go somewhere else, but I will allow the benefit of the doubt on its placement.